# insert the same text string several times based on calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to insert a letter equal to the number returned by a calculation within my code :

```
var howmanytimes = 500 / 100;
$('#mytextmultiplied').text(howmanytimes*'whatiwanttowrite');
```

The last part is obviously wrong.
Is looping the only option here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a technique:

```
var howmanytimes = 500 / 100;
var repeatedText = (howmanytimes < 1) ? '' : new Array(howmanytimes + 1).join(whatiwanttowrite);
$('#mytextmultiplied').text(repeatedText);
```

The above technique is not the fastest. For more efficient (but longer code-wise) techniques, see the answers in these similar questions:

- [Repeat Character N Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times)
- [How to create a string with n characters? How to create a string with specific length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885297/how-to-create-a-string-with-n-characters-how-to-create-a-string-with-specific-l)
- [Create a string of variable length, filled with a repeated character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343844/create-a-string-of-variable-length-filled-with-a-repeated-character)
- [Repeat String - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript)

Someday you will be able to use [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `for` loop like this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fu5x8rpn/)

```
var howmanytimes = 500 / 100; 
 //create a loop - i variable increments on each loop until it reaches 'howmanytimes'
for(var i = 0; i <= howmanytimes ; i++) {
 //here is your code to run on each loop -  
    $('#mytextmultiplied').append('whatiwanttowrite' + "<br />");
}
```